# How to install node7 on mac os?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install node 7 above on Mac OS. I used below command:

```
$brew install node
Warning: node-7.9.0 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

It says that the node-7.9.0 is already installed. But below command gives  the version of 6.9.1:

```
$ node --version
v6.9.1
```

I wander why the version show different for these two commands. How to install the node latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Run `brew link node` resolve the issue.